# wsgi error: Unable to get bucket brigade for request & apache2 redirects post to get?

Tags: flask, apache2, mod-wsgi

I want to handle a post request with a Flask app deployed on apache2 but I got unintended redirection. it also looses request body. 
I trigger a post request using a web app and access log says:
57.39.118.158 - - [22/Dec/2017:11:44:32 +0300] "POST /bridge HTTP/1.1" 301 3830 "-" "-"
57.39.118.158 - - [22/Dec/2017:11:44:32 +0300] "GET /bridge/ HTTP/1.1" 500 860 "-" "-" and error log:
"[Fri Dec 22 11:44:51.864122 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 28906:tid 139849921148672] (70008)Partial results are valid but processing is incomplete: [client 57.39.118.158:35172] mod_wsgi (pid=28906): Unable to get bucket brigade for request." 
Before, the problem "url not found" at [404 url not found error for flask app on apache2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47906730/404-url-not-found-error-for-flask-app-on-apache2) is solved.

I'm using python 3.5.2, apache 2.4, OpenSSL/1.0.2g, ubuntu 16.04, mod_wsgi4.3.0 compiled for python 3.5.1+

I have a unique conf file enabled and is like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
# The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
# the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
# redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
# specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
# match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
# value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
# However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
ServerName newocto.org
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/newocto_org.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/newocto.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt


# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

WSGIDaemonProcess bridge user=dogacandu group=dogacandu threads=5 home=/var/www/bridge/
WSGIScriptAlias /bridge /var/www/bridge/bridge.wsgi


<Directory /var/www/bridge>
WSGIProcessGroup bridge
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
Require all granted

</Directory>

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

file at /var/www/bridge/bridge.wsgi is

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys


sys.path.insert(0,'/var/www/bridge')

from bridge import app as application
```

file at /var/www/bridge/bridge.py is

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from flask import Flask


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods =['POST'])
def deliver():
    from flask import request
    raw=request.get_json(force=True)
    import mysql.connector
    dbconn= mysql.connector.connect(host='xx.20.xxx.245',port='3306',database='xxa',user='root',password='Jxxxo')
    cursor=dbconn.cursor()
    query1="""insert into bridge_test2 (email) values ('blah')"""
    query2="""insert into bridge_test2 (email) values ('{}')""".format(raw)
    cursor.execute(query1)
    dbconn.commit()
    cursor.execute(query2)
    dbconn.commit()
    dbconn.close()
    return 'ok'

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()
```

file permissions:

```
4 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root dogacandu 654 Dec 21 17:31 bridge.py  
4 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root dogacandu 117 Dec 20 18:26 bridge.wsgi
```

dogacandu is user with sudo privilage. enabled mods are:

access_compat.load  authn_core.load  authz_user.load  cgid.load     dir.load     mime.load     negotiation.load  socache_shmcb.load  status.load
alias.conf      authn_file.load  autoindex.conf   deflate.conf  env.load     mpm_event.conf    rewrite.load      ssl.conf        wsgi.conf
alias.load      authz_core.load  autoindex.load   deflate.load  filter.load  mpm_event.load    setenvif.conf     ssl.load        wsgi.load
auth_basic.load     authz_host.load  cgid.conf        dir.conf      mime.conf    negotiation.conf  setenvif.load     status.conf

may rewrite.load cause redirection problem? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say the behaviour is probably expected.

The mount point for then URL is `/bridge` and that is what you are using in the path for the URL. This gets translated to:

```
SCRIPT_NAME=/bridge
PATH_INFO=
```

when passed to Flask. With the way the route is set up, Flask is expecting to see:

```
SCRIPT_NAME=/bridge
PATH_INFO=/
```

as a result, Flask forces a redirection to force the browser to add a trailing slash.

The problem is that your handler only expects `POST` and usually a redirection will always result in the subsequent request being a `GET` which results in no handler then being found because your handler only accepts `POST`.

In short, it is a bad idea to have a `POST` handler on a route which can be the subject of automatic trailing slash redirection. In this case this is happening as you have the handler at the mount of the WSGI application when the mount point is a sub URL.

To test though that the handler worked, in your browser, use `/bridge/` in your URL instead of `/bridge`. Better still move your `POST` handler to a different route other than the mount point for the WSGI application.

As to the other strange Apache errors, you can get that sometimes when connections are pulled down due to errors when secure connections are used.

Comment: I moved my handler away from mount point and it works:)  Thanks dude!